# Reserved names in Less.js

Tags: css, less

I just figured out that some filenames will cause problems when writing Less.
I had a file names **"checkboxes.less"** that wouldn't import. After renaming it everything works as intended.

My guess is that some names are reserved for javascript variables or functions but I can't find a list of them.

**Would anyone have a list of forbidden keywords in Less.js ?**

**EDIT** : When viewing the style editor, *checkboxes.less* is not imported. No error is shown in the console.

**EDIT 2 :** [File structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg9lE.png)

**EDIT 3:** Also doesn't work on *confirm.less*

Comment: I doubt there is such a thing. You can check here the functions: http://lesscss.org/functions/

Comment: There are no functions related to checkboxes, and I worked on many projects that shared the same or similar names, and never had this problem. It must be something else that caused the problem. Sometimes the localhost needs a full path of the file to work properly.

Comment: @TorjescuSergiu I tried giving it the full path but it didn't do anything.
Renaming from checkboxes.less to checkboxies.less solved the problem.

Comment: maybe if you can provide a picture with the file structure I can take a look

Answer (score 0):

When importing a less file use it like this, not like the css:

```
@import "library"; // library.less
@import "typo.css";
```

Comment: Thanks !
See *Edit 2* where I posted the file structure along with the first lines of *style.less*

Comment: yeah, so use the import without the extension and tell me if it works

Comment: Nope, still not loaded.

Comment: remove the ./ from the path so just put @import "checkboxes";

Comment: Only changing the *checkboxes* part in *checkboxes.less* changed the way it's loaded.
I have tried to import *./checkboxes.less*, *checkboxes*, *checkboxes.less*. None of these seems to do the trick.